# ERROR:Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I am trying to run this source code where I get from *https://github.com/kishancs2020/TicketBookingServiceJunitTesting* Github in my Jenkins to see the pipeline that has created in Jenkinsfile of the source code.

I already update maven, java version as to fix it but still the error is same.  I also has go through this link *http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException* but can't find the solution. Any suggestion to fix this error.

```
+ mvn clean -f TicketBookingServiceJunitTesting
POM file TicketBookingServiceJunitTesting specified with the -f/--file command line argument does not exist
[[1;34mINFO[m] Scanning for projects...
[[1;31mERROR[m] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-readable POM /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ervicejunittesting-master_master/TicketBookingServiceJunitTesting: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ervicejunittesting-master_master/TicketBookingServiceJunitTesting (No such file or directory) @ 
 @ 
[[1;31mERROR[m] The build could not read 1 project -> [1m[Help 1][m
[[1;31mERROR[m]   
[[1;31mERROR[m]   The project  (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ervicejunittesting-master_master/TicketBookingServiceJunitTesting) has 1 error
[[1;31mERROR[m]     Non-readable POM /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ervicejunittesting-master_master/TicketBookingServiceJunitTesting: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ervicejunittesting-master_master/TicketBookingServiceJunitTesting (No such file or directory)
[[1;31mERROR[m] 
[[1;31mERROR[m] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the [1m-e[m switch.
[[1;31mERROR[m] Re-run Maven using the [1m-X[m switch to enable full debug logging.
[[1;31mERROR[m] 
[[1;31mERROR[m] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1m[Help 1][m http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
```

This is the pom.xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.infotech.book.ticket.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>TicketBookingRestApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>TicketBookingRestApp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

May I know why it says pom.xml is not readable?. The pipeline only success at git repo & clean stage only.

Comment: It looks like the folder TicketBookingServiceJunitTesting does not exist in the  working directory (which gets created when you run the build) . Please put the checkout path or try mvn clean as the root folder you have checkout may be https://github.com/kishancs2020/TicketBookingServiceJunitTesting . Just a hunch

Answer (score 1):

`-f` flag in maven is used to specify the pom file other than `pom.xml` file in current folder that's the reason you are getting the exception.

If you want to test a particular test class `-Dtest` switch to specify the test class

REF: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html